# How to upgrade a GPO force-installed Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We develop a network security product, incorporating a chrome extension, currently installed by the ExtensionInstallForcelist value in GPO.

One of our product features is that surfing the Internet/intranet is separated in to several trust zones - and the chrome extension is responsible for making the switch between different browser windows running in different zones. Sometimes, the update_url in the CRX will not be accessible to browsers running in all trust zones. Since Chrome "imports" the extension upon the first installation from the CRX location specified in the initial XML file, I am at a loss as to how to upgrade the extension when our software is upgraded. So far I am only seeing the following options:

- manually edit each user's "Preferences" file and Extensions\ directories under Chrome's AppData location (this to me is hackish, unstable and I would rather avoid it...)
- Use a static file:/// url as the update_url in the manifest.json (but this has the limit of a specific drive, directory and file having to be present)
- manually edit the master_preferences file to install and/or upgrade our extension (this is strongly discouraged by google, here: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453?hl=en

Does anyone have any experience with deploying Chrome extension for corporate applications and upgrading them in a way I missed (after much, much digging...)?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using a hardcoded file:/// url as the update_url as we could not find a better way of doing it (we chose not to publish the extension on the chrome appstore).