# AutoUpdate Chrome Extension GPO

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension published via GPO with the chrome policies: ExtensionInstallForcelist and ExtensionInstallSources.
I also have an updates.xml file with describe the .crx version, the appid and and the url of the .crx to download.

The problem is, that I forgot to add the "update_url" property to my manifest.json file to autoupdate check the version of the extension.

Is it possible to force user's extension update without this property?

Comment: I think you cannot do it without the "update_url" property based on this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050526). They ended up using the update_url to update their extension. Just check the other option of the user in the linked SO question if you get any idea from it. For more information, check also this [Autoupdating](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate) of the Chrome extension documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For people with this issue, you can simply try to

1) Remove the ExtensionInstallForcelist entry.

2) Then have the users run Chrome : this will delete the old extension.

3) Then you set again the ExtensionInstallForcelist entry with the correct extension.

It requires a bit of coordination but it works.